# How to bind my UIButton title to my ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I want to bind `UIButton` title to a `BehaviorSubject<String>` in my ViewModel. I do it in `Label` like below:

```cs
//ViewModel
var fullName = BehaviorSubject<String?>(value: "")

//ViewController
vm.fullName.bind(to: fullNameLabel.rx.text).disposed(by: bag)
```

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following `RxCocoa`, `Reactive` also extend UIButton `title` or `attributedTitle` to bind it

Please check this [RxSwift/UIButton+Rx.swift] link (https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/iOS/UIButton%2BRx.swift)

```swift
extension Reactive where Base: UIButton {

    /// Reactive wrapper for `setTitle(_:for:)`
    public func title(for controlState: UIControl.State = []) -> Binder<String?> {
        return Binder(self.base) { button, title -> Void in
            button.setTitle(title, for: controlState)
        }
    }
}

extension Reactive where Base: UIButton {

    /// Reactive wrapper for `setAttributedTitle(_:controlState:)`
    public func attributedTitle(for controlState: UIControl.State = []) -> Binder<NSAttributedString?> {
        return Binder(self.base) { button, attributedTitle -> Void in
            button.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, for: controlState)
        }
    }

}
```

**So you can bind your full name BehaviorSubject to button like your sample code label**

```swift
vm.fullName.bind(to: someButton.rx.title()).disposed(by: bag)
```

Comment: Referencing instance method 'title(for:)' on 'Reactive' requires that 'String._ObjectiveCType' (aka 'NSString') inherit from 'UIButton'

Answer (score 7):

The correct way is to use the `title()` binder.

```
vm.fullName
    .bind(to: button.rx.title())
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way using rx swift :

```
vm.buttonTitle.bind(to: button.rx.title(for: .normal)).disposed(by: bag)
```